# conditional spending from P2WSH address

Tags: script, segregated-witness, input-script, signrawtransaction, input

What im doing wrong?
Sinse I found out  that Bitcoin is programmable money Im trying to use it potential.
Using this site https://improvein.github.io/bitcoin-forge/?#/script/create I’ve created a conditional  script that holds 2 time locks for two pub keys.

OP_IF 1694275749 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP 03cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ELSE 1694277749 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP 036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ENDIF

Script 63051694275749b1752103cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535ac67051694277749b17521036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23ac68

Used this script to create with this tool
https://improvein.github.io/bitcoin-forge/?#/address/create Payment to Witness Script Hash
address  bc1qes2v6ts5ckxuz5mkwdeukcn62hkac05kf97gugc4jnu3kj3wg5as3nes34

Now I’m using bitcoin core cli to sign the input and create raw transaction. And I’m completely stack at this point. How and what to sign and how to put this puzzle for unlocking transaction.

The scope of this script is to give to family member some funds locked in future with ability to be spend it with one of 2 privet keys. If he loose his key, I can spend it with op_else condition.  I will provide some data

```
gettxout 14290ef656c05f8e0c06b6d99a6ae72c77a8809b3a69dd5fb00f07ce9cee1637  vout 133


{
  "bestblock": "0000000000000000000528fb0e92c1e79378a1b241eb144ca0f97054fdf42dfb",
  "confirmations": 155,
  "value": 0.00007726,
  "scriptPubKey": {
    "asm": "0 cc14cd2e14c58dc153767373cb627a55eddc3e96497c8e231594f91b4a2e453b",
    "desc": "addr(bc1qes2v6ts5ckxuz5mkwdeukcn62hkac05kf97gugc4jnu3kj3wg5as3nes34)#k8s5es0p",
    "hex": "0020cc14cd2e14c58dc153767373cb627a55eddc3e96497c8e231594f91b4a2e453b",
    "address": "bc1qes2v6ts5ckxuz5mkwdeukcn62hkac05kf97gugc4jnu3kj3wg5as3nes34",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash"
  },
  "coinbase": false
}
```

the locking script

```
{
  "asm": "1692429480 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP OP_IF 03cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ELSE 1692602280 OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP 036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23 OP_CHECKSIG OP_ENDIF",
  "desc": "raw(04a86ce064b175632103cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535ac6704a80fe364b17521036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23ac68)#r3dcxvh2",
  "type": "nonstandard",
  "p2sh": "38cTqVJf1jPBDCjg8wKdFx476uHX3qgEaB",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 69672524bb7737429280e9c862b3fdcea0dc22037cbaaa755d6132b4841811e4",
    "desc": "wsh(raw(04a86ce064b175632103cd18ace3a339fcd0039fd87d7a7a8377537cd9a9f2afa2a3e76f40e53112a535ac6704a80fe364b17521036bb176ed8fe2e38949a63ff964eed3c5e79fd88ac011cad1eecf22702ea65d23ac68))#7uzehfsr",
    "hex": "002069672524bb7737429280e9c862b3fdcea0dc22037cbaaa755d6132b4841811e4",
    "address": "bc1qd9nj2f9mwum59y5qa8yx9vlae6sdcgsr0ja25a2avyetfpqcz8jqg69shh",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "p2sh-segwit": "3NqDPiKTsbYA18GRWzrsE5wYYxGhH9XS96"
  }
}
```

and 2nd question

how segwit time locked script will work considering The "Year 2038 problem" when issue arises because a 32-bit signed integer can represent a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 seconds, which is approximately 68 years. The Unix epoch started on January 1, 1970, so adding 68 years to this date brings us to January 19, 2038. so question is : funds time locked after January 19, 2038 will be spendable same way like today?